# Unresolved dependency: net.sourceforge.htmlunit in SBT

Tags: sbt, htmlunit

My `build.sbt` has the following content:

```
name := "hello-world"

version := "1.0"

scalaVersion := "2.10.3"

libraryDependencies += "net.sourceforge.htmlunit" %% "htmlunit" % "2.13"
```

When I perform `update` in sbt console it says:

```
[error] (*:update) sbt.ResolveException: unresolved dependency: net.sourceforge.htmlunit#htmlunit_2.10;2.13: not found
```

What should I do to make sbt find this library?

Answer (score 6):

Just use a single `%` instead of double `%%` in the dependency.

```
libraryDependencies += "net.sourceforge.htmlunit" % "htmlunit" % "2.13"
```

`%%` is only required when the path of the jar contains Scala version which is not a case for the dependency. I figured it out consulting mvnrepository - http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/net.sourceforge.htmlunit/htmlunit/2.13. Just hover over the 'Download(JAR)' link and you can see the full path.

Note: By default sbt uses the standard Maven2 repository. In case you have dependent jars that cannot be found in the default repo, then you need to add custom resolvers like this

```
resolvers += "custom_repo" at "url"
```

For this particular example resolvers are not required since htmlunit is present in default repo.